# Negation of monotonicity of a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, inequality, continuity, monotone-functions

So I am given a continuous function mapping a connected domain to the reals, i.e 
$$f: (a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
I want to show that if $f$ is not strictly monotone and f is continuous, we have $x,y,z \in (a,b)$ with $x < y < z$ such that:
$$f(x) \leq f(y) \text{ and } f(y) \geq f(z)$$

or

$$f(x) \geq f(y) \text{ and } f(y) \leq f(z)$$

As for what I've tried, using the negation of strictly monotone, we have that $f$ must be increasing and decreasing in two intervals $[x_1,x_2]$ and $[x_3, x_4]$ i.e:
$$f(x_1) \leq f(x_2) \text{ and } f(x_3) \geq f(x_4)$$

or

$$f(x_1) \geq f(x_2) \text{ and } f(x_3) \leq f(x_4)$$

The problem comes when I look to combine the two into a single inequality. In an effort to combine these, the only way I see of doing it (directly) would be casewise. If anyone could provide a hint or (less preferred) a complete direct proof I would appreciate it.

Comment: You're almost there. For the first pair of inequalities take $y=x_2$ if $f(x_2)\ge f(x_3)$ or $y=x_3$ if $f(x_2)\le f(x_3)$. For the second the opposite.

Comment: @SergeiGolovan Ah,that was so darn obvious. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use proof by contradiction. If your statement is false, then for every $x < y < z$, we have
$$f(x) > f(y) \quad \textrm{ or } \quad f(y) < f(z)$$
and
$$f(x) < f(y) \quad \textrm{ or } \quad f(y) > f(z).$$

Comment: So I did do it this way initially, but it felt like a bit of a cop out, I guess I kinda wanted to derive the result as directly as possible. (Not a constructionist I just wanted to think of it that way)